# Azure functions deploy issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am deploying some azure functions to Function App through CI-CD pipeline. Functions are getting deployed successfully. When I deploy them locally they are getting executed successfully, but when I deploy through  pipeline and run them I'm getting an error :

> "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0."

Comment: Do you have any kind of connection string which may not be set on the target environment? Like a missing environment variable, in case a .NET a .json file which is left as "Do not copy"?

Comment: I have taken a c# application.. where i am getting connection string like this 

 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();